# Python: Define Object within a Class

Tags: python, class, object, keyerror

Very new to Python and could do with some help. How do I go about referencing members in a class? 
I have two csv files. One contains a series of parts and associated material ID. The other is a material index that contains materials ID's and some information about that material.

My intention is to create a third file that contains all of the parts, their material Id's and the information if present in the material index.

I have created a class for the material index and am trying to access objects in this class using material Ids from the part file however, this is not working and I am unsure as to why. Any help is appreciated:

```
class material():
    def __init__(self, name, ftu, e, nu):
        self.name = name
        self.ftu = ftu
        self.e = e
        self.nu = nu

def extract_FTU_Strain(input_file_parts,input_file_FTU,output_file):

    parts = {}
    materials = {}

    for aline in open(input_file_FTU, 'r'):
        comma_split = aline.strip().split(',')
        name = comma_split[1]
        ftu = comma_split[8]
        e = comma_split[9]
        nu = comma_split[7]



        try:
            materials[int(comma_split[0])] = material(comma_split[1],comma_split[8],comma_split[9],comma_split[7])
            #materials[comma_split[0]] = material(comma_split[1],comma_split[8],comma_split[9],comma_split[7])
        except:
            pass


    for i in open(input_file_parts, 'r'):
        semicolon_split = i.strip().split(';')


        material_id = semicolon_split[3]


        part = semicolon_split[0]
        part_id = semicolon_split[1]

        material_name = materials[material_id].name
        FTU = materials[material_id].ftu
        Stress = materials[material_id].e
        output.write(','.join([part,part_id,material_name,material_id,FTU,Stress]) + '\n') 












    output = open (output_file,'w')
    output.write('Part Title, Part Id, Material Id, FTU, e' + '\n')
    output.close()

import sys

input_file_parts = '/parttable.csv'
input_file_FTU = '/Material_Index.csv'
output_file = '/PYTHONTESTING123.csv'
extract_FTU_Strain(input_file_parts,input_file_FTU,output_file)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please cut down your code to the minimal needed to demonstrate the problem. At the very least, remove the commented-out lines before posting.

Comment: So I believe that I have created the class successfully but I am getting an error when trying to extract information from the class:
line: `material_name = materials[material_id].name` 
I think this is because material_id comes from a part list file and the class has been generated from the material index.

Comment: **What error**?

Comment: Sorry that would have been helpful!! Key Error: 'Material id'. This is the first instance of `semicolon_split[3]`. I think this issue maybe due to trying to compare a string and an integer as I have just realised that material_id is a string but [int(comma_split[0]]) obviously must be an integer

Comment: But that error does not have anything at all to do with accessing data in a class, but only to do with looking things up within a dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I feel I am not explaining myself particularly well as I am new to Python and using the wrong terminology which I appreciate isn't helpful. I was trying to access information in what I thought was a class (material) but you are saying that the syntax is for looking in a dictionary and not a class?

Comment: No. `materials` is a dictionary, whose keys are integers and whose values are class instances. But the error you're seeing is in looking up the element in the dictionary, not in accessing the information in the instance once you've got it.

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense. Thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in the comments you said your error is in `materials[material_id]` make `material_id` an integer as it was an integer when you created the object.

You created it this way

`materials[int(comma_split[0])]=...`

But later called it without converting `material_id` to an int. Do this before calling it in your for loop to write in the output.

```
material_id = int(material_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misinterpreted your question, but going off the line 'How do I go about referencing members in a class?' you can reference member variables like so:

```
class Demonstration:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def printMembers(self):
        print self.a, self.b
```

So inside the class you can use `self.someVariable` to reference member variables.

If you want to access them outside of the class:

```
myclass.myvariable
```

I'll happily edit the answer if I have't quite understood your question or if there is a specific error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what error you have, could you put the traceback? Anyway, you are creating a class instance at the time of assignment. For more elegant programming, you could simply do:

`m = materials(name, ftu, e, nu)`

This way you can access the instance variables like this:

```
m.name
m.ftu
...
```

And try, except -> pass it's very dangerous

Comment: So I guess my question is how do you specify which name in your class you want with the syntax m.name. Surely this could reference any instance since every member in the class has an associated name, ftu, u and nu?

Comment: Exactly. When you create a class instance you have access to variables and methods using var.name. In python there is no private visibility as defined in java or other languages. By default the visibility is public